# how to update just one column of a table by csv using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I used the following code to update one column of a table, but it also delete values of 
other columns, I couldn't find the reason. Please help.

> $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($data[0]=='NULL'){
            $import="UPDATE tst_stores SET store_image_url = 'http://admin.showcasejewellers.com.au/uploads/default_store.jpg' ";
        } 
        else{
            $import="UPDATE tst_stores SET store_image_url = 'http://admin.showcasejewellers.com.au/uploads/" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]) . ".jpg'";
        }


    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());


}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You need to add a `WHERE` statement to just update one row. That will be something like: `WHERE id=506`

Comment: As you see this will update different rows by using "while" so it was not the problem is effected on other columns also. Also I used and variable $i and increment it end of the loop and used WHERE id = $i

Comment: It won't "update different rows". It'll update all rows. Effectively you could run only the last query - result will be almost the same. Add `WHERE` clause to your query

Comment: @user3206125 even when you use a while loop you still will need a `WHERE` statement. When you use the query like you do now you will update all rows for that column. Also I see you use mysql you better use `MSQYLi` OR `PDO`

Comment: OK thanks for all I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SQL`  query is wrong. You have to specify which row you want to update using `WHERE` clause. For example

```
 UPDATE tst_stores SET store_image_url = 'http://admin.showcasejewellers.com.au/uploads/default_store.jpg' WHERE tst_stores.id = 10;
```

This will update only the row where column id is equal to 10.

**Note:** I just assumed table `tst_stores` has `id` column is exists and primary key. You have to change accordingly

Just check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) for further reading.